# Converting Some Code to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys, I have some code that I found that I would rather use as jQuery instead of direct JavaScript. Hopefully you guys can help me convert it:

```
var sub = document.getElementById('submit');
sub.parentNode.removeChild(sub);
document.getElementById('btn-area').appendChild(sub);
document.getElementById('submit').tabIndex = 6;
if ( typeof _some_var != 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById('some-textarea').value = _some_var;
}
document.getElementById('something').style.direction = 'ltr';
```

The reason I want to do this is because FireFox is telling me that `sub` is null when it is used on the second line. This happens because that code runs before the the `submit` button appears. So naturally I would like to use jQuery for the purpose of running the code after everything is ready. Yes, I know it's possible to do that in direct JavaScript as well, but I would rather have jQuery either way.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to call removeChild because when you use appendchild it will first remove the child from the current position and then only append it to the new position.

Comment: Thank you pulse, like I said I am inheriting this code but I will definitely make that change to prevent having unnecessary code. Thanks again!

Comment: Ooh Ooh, read mine. I always recommend using JQuery for dom manipulation, or else you can't trust it'll work cross-browser.

Comment: That's another reason why I was thinking about using it, but the consensus seems to be that it isn't necessary in this situation, perhaps it is too basic to leverage any of the advantages jQuery might have. Though the jQuery form definitely does look a lot neater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to use jQuery for this purpose. Assuming you do not already have a load event handler:

```
window.onload = function() { 
   // your code
};
```

Or throw it right before the end body tag, or to be more specific anywhere in the source after the submit button - there's nothing really dirty about it.

```
<script src="your-code.js"></script>
</body>
```

However, a quick jQuery rewrite..

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').appendTo('#btn-area').attr('tabIndex', 6);
    if ( typeof yourVar != 'undefined' ) {
        $('#textarea').val( yourVar );
    }
    $('#something').css('direction', 'ltr');
});
```

Did not test.

Comment: I already fixed the problem mentioned in the post by putting this in the footer, I just figured it would make more sense to have this code as jQuery, but I guess that is not necessary then.

Comment: So I'm guessing using jQuery in this situation would only add unnecessary overhead, I won't use it then. Thanks for the conversion, regardless.

Comment: Pretty much, and would be inconsistent with all the rest of your DOM Scripting if you have lots of scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
var sub_html = $('#submit').html();
$('#submit').html('');
$('#btn-area').html(sub_html);
$('#submit').attr('tabindex', 6);
if(typeof _some_var != 'undefined')
{
    $('#some-textarea').val(_some_var);
}
$('#something').css('direction', 'ltr');
```